# Cant fetch SavedPost

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview

My app has an option to save posts for users to watch later. The code is:

```
func savedPost(for cell: FirstView) {

    guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    var post = self.posts[indexPath.item]

    guard let currentuserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let targetUid = post.user.uid

    guard let postId = post.id else { return }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("save_post").child(currentuserId).child(postId)

    if post.hasSaved {

        ref.removeValue { (err, _) in

            if let _ = err {
                showErr(info: NSLocalizedString("failtoUnsave", comment: ""), subInfo: tryLater)
                return
            }

            post.hasSaved = false
            self.posts[indexPath.item] = post
            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        }

    } else {

        let values = ["userId": targetUid]

        ref.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in

            if let _ = err {
                showErr(info: NSLocalizedString("failtoSave", comment: ""), subInfo: tryLater)
            }

            post.hasSaved = true
            self.posts[indexPath.item] = post
            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }
}
```

With this code my firebase database in "save_post" has -> currentUseruId -> postid -> postUserId.
On ProfileController users can view saved Posts from "savedPost" Tab. The code is:

```
var savedPosts = [Post]()

fileprivate func fetchSaved() {

    var userIds = [String]()
    var postIds = [String]()

    guard let uid = self.user?.uid else { return }

    let getIDsRef = Database.database().reference().child("save_post").child(uid)
    let query = getIDsRef.queryOrderedByKey()

    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]

        dictionary?.forEach({ (key,value) in

            guard let dic = value as? [String: String] else { return }

            postIds.append(key)
            userIds.append(dic["userId"] ?? "")
        })

        var i = 0

        while i < userIds.count {
            self.fetchPostsWithUserIDPostID(userID: userIds[i], postID: postIds[i])
            i += 1
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUserIDPostID(userID: String, postID: String) {

    let getPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("video_list")

    getPostRef.child(userID).child(postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID)

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            let user = User(uid: userID, dictionary: dict)
            var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)
            post.id = postID

            guard let currentUserUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postID).child(currentUserUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if let value = snapshot.value as? Int, value == 1 {
                    post.hasLiked = true
                } else {
                    post.hasLiked = false
                }

                post.hasSaved = true

                self.savedPosts.append(post)
                self.savedPosts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                    return p1.creationDate.compare(p2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
                })

                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            })
        })
    })
}
```

However, when I click "savedPost" tab, there is no post shown. I don't know where my mistake is. I have all the necessary code under all override func collectionView(....). I believe the error should come from the code listed above. I am sincerely looking for help to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of things going on here.  It would be good to throw some print statements in there to make sure that 1) the data you're getting back from the database looks like what you expect, and 2) that you're properly parsing it into `Post` objects.  Do you have your cells defined properly for your `CollectionView`?  Also, I don't see where you are defining the data source for the `CollectionView`.